# Convert triplets to matrix in R

Tags: r, triplet

I have triplets and want to convert them to the matrix.

This is my code:

```
data = data.frame(row = c(1,2,3), column = c(2,3,1), value = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.5));
m <- matrix(0, nrow = max(data$row), ncol = max(data$column));
m[ data$row, data$col ] = data$value;
```

The output is

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  0.1  0.1  0.1
[2,]  0.2  0.2  0.2
[3,]  0.5  0.5  0.5
```

Desire output is

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  0    0.1  0
[2,]  0    0    0.2
[3,]  0.5  0    0
```

How can I do that without loop?

Comment: Since you need zeros, see, also, `xtabs`: `xtabs(value ~ row + column, data)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
m[cbind(data[,1], data[,2])] <- data$value
```

Or

```
 m[as.matrix(data[1:2])] <- data$value
 m
 #    [,1] [,2] [,3]
 #[1,]  0.0  0.1  0.0
 #[2,]  0.0  0.0  0.2
 #[3,]  0.5  0.0  0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
# just in case your data are not ordered by row value, order them:
data<-data[order(data$row),]

# directly create your matrix by replacing "by default" 0 with data$value in the right positions:
m <- matrix(replace(rep(0, max(data$column)*max(data$row)), data$col+(0:(max(data$row)-1))*max(data$row), data$value), 
            nrow=max(data$row), ncol=max(data$column), byrow=T)

> m
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]  0.0  0.1  0.0
#[2,]  0.0  0.0  0.2
#[3,]  0.5  0.0  0.0
```

Comment: Akrun's way is more simple, but yours is useful too! Thanks!

Comment: FedorenkoKristina, you're welcome and I totally agree about @akrun solution (which I upvoted), I just wanted to give another more direct (although a bit more complicated) option ;-)

Comment: @CathG I never thought about this method :-)

Comment: @akrun, maybe because it is a bit far-fetched... ;-)